# FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL fails after app jettisoned, restarted

Tags: facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

My iOS app is frequently jettisoned during FUS to the Facebook login page. I'm working on reducing memory usage but I'd like to guarantee the login works even if my app is jettisoned.

So far, though, I can't get this to work. When I press the Login button, my app re-launches successfully. I get the url passed into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as well as my `appDelegate`'s openURL, and I call `[[FBSession alloc] initWithAppID]` which returns a session in the `SessionCreated` state.

Then I call

```
openActiveSessionWithPermissions:array allowLoginUI:NO completionHandler:^{stuff}
```

But when I call `handleOpenURL` on the active session, my `completionHandler` is not called and I am not logged in.

Can someone help me with how to get the FB SDK ready to accept the returned URL? Or is this even possible?

I'm using v3.8.0 of the FB SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the correct sequence of calls. `authStr` is the url passed into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

```
bool IOSFacebookDriver::OpenAuthToken(const std::string &authStr)
{
    NSString *authString = [NSString stringWithCString:authStr.c_str() encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *authURL = [NSURL URLWithString:authString];
    FBAccessTokenData *token = [FBAccessTokenData createTokenFromFacebookURL:authURL appID:mNSAppId urlSchemeSuffix:[FBSession defaultUrlSchemeSuffix]];
    bool tokenAccepted = [[FBSession activeSession] openFromAccessTokenData:token completionHandler:^(FBSession* session, FBSessionState state, NSError* error)
     {<completion handler>};
}
```